# WinFoms: Not able to load the form. Error: Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, vsto

I am trying to load the form of a published application. I am getting the below error message:

**Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.**

searched in google, found some articles but those are not resolved my problem.

Can you help on this ?

Thanks
Koti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Power Pack controls need to be installed on each PC that will use the app. See [Deploying Applications That Reference Power Packs Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488314%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (VS2008SP1).
This will be solve your problem.